# How can I get the git history of a given object definition?

Tags: r, git

When working on a package I'm often wondering if the function has been modified recently.

The function might have been moved from script to script, its code or documentation might have changed.

It would be really great to be able to call : `git_history(my_function, branch = "main")` and get for instance a data frame with :

- commit_id
- commit_text
- author
- timestamp
- file
- code (object definition, ideally but not necessarily including roxygen2 block)

From this and using the {diffobj} package we'll be able to navigate the changes easily.

It would be great if it'd work with all objects but that might be easier to do with only functions using the srcref, and we'd get 95% of the value this way.

Even better would be to have an additional column with the object name and have everything in a single df, but maybe that'd be a bit expensive to do ?

I have some ideas on how to achieve this but I'm not sure if that'd be efficient, and I don't want to spend time on this if it's already been done. I'll come back to this to self answer if I don't get a satisfying answer.

The ways I see are :

- fetch commit list using git command
- loop on them, and check them out into a temp folder
- In each iteration parse `getParseData(parse(file = ))` all the files and extract the definitions, or maybe just regex them, or source all files and extract srcrefs (this won't give us the roxygen2 stuff nor non function definitions)
- build a row of the df above for every commit(and every object definition if we go this route)
- keep only oldest for consecutive duplicates of code
- remove temp folder, return data frame

I think it'd be great to have template somewhere for how to do some language aware version control with R and git so let's do it here.

Comment: I'm no expert in git commands but isn't `git blame` what you're looking for? (without the dataframe output I mean)

Comment: Ah no you want to track a function between files and `git blame` is only on one file

Comment: `TIL` we have [`gitr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gitr/), [`git2r`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/git2r/), and [`git4r`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/git4r/), with no direct link between the different packages. T'would be nice to have some collaboration between the packages :-/

Comment: There is also `gert` :D

Comment: @bretauv and even if the function stays in the same file git blame will show updates in lines outside of the function definition

Answer (score 1):

I provide a function to fetch the history of all functions on a repo for a given branch, and a function to review the history of a given object using the fetched history.

The former function might take a bit of time on a big repo but I've put some progress bars to help.

Some args to limit the file scope and period would help too. This should be in a package.

```
git_history <- function(repo = ".", branch = "main") {
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # get commit history + meta data
  log_cmd <- sprintf("git -C '%s' log %s --pretty=format:'%%h,%%ae,%%cI,%%s'", repo, branch)
  commits <- system(log_cmd, intern = TRUE)
  
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # wrangle into data.frame, taking into account that commas in commit title are not separators
  commits_df <- purrr::map_dfr(
    strsplit(commits, ","),
    ~ tibble::tibble(
      commit = .x[[1]],
      author = .x[[2]],
      time = .x[[3]] |> sub("T", "", x = _) |> sub("+", " (+", x = _) |> paste0(")"),
      description = paste(.x[-(1:3)], collapse = ","),
    ), 
    .progress = TRUE
  )
  
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Fetch affected files for every commit
  get_affected_files <- function(commit) {
    cmd <- sprintf("git -C '%s' show --name-only --pretty=format: %s", repo, commit)
    files <- system(cmd, intern = TRUE)
    # keep only R files from the R folder
    files <- grep("R/.*[.](R|r)$", files, value = TRUE)
    files
  }
  
  files_df <-
    commits_df |>
    dplyr::mutate(file = purrr::map(commit, get_affected_files, .progress = TRUE)) |>
    tidyr::unnest_longer(file)
  
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Fetch objects for every affected file
  parse_commit_file  <- function(commit, file) {
    cmd <- sprintf("git -C '%s' show %s:'%s'", repo, commit, file)
    file_code <- suppressWarnings(tryCatch(
      system(cmd, intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE), 
      error = function(e) "REMOVED"
    ))
    parsed_data <- try(getParseData(parse(text = file_code, keep.source = TRUE), includeText = TRUE), silent = TRUE)
    # non syntactic edits (e.g. containing conflict markers) are skipped
    if (inherits(parsed_data, "try-error")) return(NULL) 
    assignment_ids <- parsed_data$parent[parsed_data$token == "LEFT_ASSIGN"]
    top_level_assignment_ids <- parsed_data$id[parsed_data$id %in% assignment_ids & parsed_data$parent == 0]
    if (!length(top_level_assignment_ids)) return(NULL)
    obj_names <- sapply(top_level_assignment_ids, function(x) parsed_data$text[which(parsed_data$parent == x)[[1]]])
    parsed_data$id <- ifelse(parsed_data$parent < 0, abs(parsed_data$parent), parsed_data$id)
    parsed_data <- parsed_data[parsed_data$id %in% top_level_assignment_ids, c("id", "text")]
    code <- tapply(parsed_data$text, parsed_data$id, function(x) paste(x, collapse = "\n"))
    file_data <- data.frame(object = obj_names, code = code)
    file_data
  }
  
  rleid <- function(x) {
    x <- rle(x)$lengths
    rep(seq_along(x), times=x)
  }
  
  
  objects_df <-
    files_df |>
    dplyr::mutate(object = purrr::pmap(list(commit, file), parse_commit_file, .progress = TRUE)) |>
    tidyr::unnest(object)
  
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Remove redundancies and format into proper history df
  history <-
    objects_df |>
    # add NA code and file for every combination of commit and object
    tidyr::complete(tidyr::nesting(commit, author, time, description), object) |>
    # arrange chronologically to prepare for rleid() below
    dplyr::arrange(time) |> 
    dplyr::group_by(object) |> 
    # fill these NAs to reflect actual status at every step
    tidyr::fill(code, file) |>
    # identify running length sequences (spans in which object didn't change)
    dplyr::mutate(id = rleid(paste(file, code))) |>
    dplyr::ungroup() |>
    # keep only 1st and last during unchanged span
    dplyr::slice(
      .by = c(object, id), 
      unique(c(1, dplyr::n()))
    ) |>
    # replace file and code with intuitive values for diffobj in review_object_history()
    tidyr::replace_na(list(file = "none", code = "")) |>
    dplyr::select(-id)
  
  history
}

review_object_history <- function(git_history, object, ascending = TRUE) {
  diff_data <- git_history |> 
    dplyr::arrange(time) |>
    dplyr::filter(object == .env$object) |> 
    dplyr::transmute(
      banner = sprintf("%s<br>%s<br>%s<br>%s<br>%s", time, commit, author, description, file),
      file,
      code = strsplit(code, "\n")
    )
  
  if (ascending) {
    i <- 0
  } else {
    i <- nrow(diff_data)
  }
  tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
  press <- ""
  repeat {
    step <- prod(ifelse(c(press == "", ascending), 1, -1))
    i <- i + step
    if (i %in% c(0, nrow(diff_data))) break
    break_ <- FALSE
    while(identical(diff_data$code[[i+1]], diff_data$code[[i]]) &&
          identical(diff_data$file[[i+1]], diff_data$file[[i]])) {
      i <- i + step
      if (i %in% c(0, nrow(diff_data))) {
        break_ <- TRUE
        break
      }
    }
    if (break_) break
    
    x <- diffobj::diffChr(
      diff_data$code[[i]], 
      diff_data$code[[i+1]], 
      mode = "sidebyside", 
      tar.banner = paste("older:", diff_data$banner[[i]]),
      cur.banner = paste("newer:", diff_data$banner[[i+1]]),
      ignore.white.space = FALSE,
      convert.hz.white.space = FALSE,
      strip.sgr = FALSE,
      trim = FALSE,
      context = -1,
      pager = list(file.path = tmp)
    )
    print(x)
    press <- readline("Press ENTER to continue, or any other key then ENTER to go back: ")
  }
}

hist_data <- git_history() 
review_object_history(hist_data, "myobject")
```

Comment: This is much better than the previous version but I think we can do a bit better. In most cases a function stays in the same script, so we might start `review_object_history()` at a given commit (or first/last), check every file for the given object, and then whenever we move forward or back we check that file first and others otherwise, and we cache whatever we compute that is expensive.

Comment: in that case commit = "HEAD" and descending = TRUE might be better defaults since the first commit doesn't have a fixed name and that functions we're interested in exist more in the last commit than the first. We should be able to precompute as we do now too, so we have a fast function (unless the new feature proves fast enough)